# Authorisation error when running airflow via cloud composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I get an error when trying to run DAG from cloud composer using the GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.

Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'gs://xxxxxx/xxxx.csv', 
and when I follow the URL link to the error ...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie     or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-    project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I have configured the Cloud Storage connection ...

Conn Id   My_Cloud_Storage

Conn Type Google Cloud Platform

Project Id   xxxxxx

Keyfile Path   /home/airflow/gcs/data/xxx.json

Keyfile JSON

Scopes (comma seperated)   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Code ..

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

default_dag_args = {
    # The start_date describes when a DAG is valid / can be run. Set this to a
    # fixed point in time rather than dynamically, since it is evaluated every
    # time a DAG is parsed. See:
    # https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 15),
}
with models.DAG(
        'Ian_gcs_to_BQ_Test',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    load_csv = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='gcs_to_bq_test',
        bucket='xxxxx',
        source_objects=['xxxx.csv'],
        destination_project_dataset_table='xxxx.xxxx.xxxx',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='My_Cloud_Storage',
        schema_fields=[
            {'name':'AAAA','type':'INTEGER','mode':'NULLABLE'},
            {'name':'BBB_NUMBER','type':'INTEGER','mode':'NULLABLE'},   
        ],
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        dag=dag)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is not related to BigQuery as you have not specified `bigquery_conn_id` ?

Comment: I tried creating a Big Query Connection but it made no difference. It's still an authorization error and saying invalid location but I've double checked the location and it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok , now it's fixed.
Turns out it wasn't working because of the header row in the file, once I removed that it worked fine.
Pretty annoying, completely misleading error messages about invalid locations and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same looking error. What fixed it for me was adding the location of my dataset to my operator. So first, check the dataset information if you are not sure the location. Then add it as a parameter in your operator. For example, my dataset was in `us-west1` and I was using an operator that looked like this:

```
    check1 = BigQueryCheckOperator(task_id='check_my_event_data_exists',
                       sql="""
                        select count(*) > 0
                        from my_project.my_dataset.event
                         """,
                       use_legacy_sql=False,
                       location="us-west1")   # THIS WAS THE FIX IN MY CASE
```

GCP error messages don't seem to be very good.